# parsing file using sax parser with two nodes have the same name

Tags: java, android

I'm parsing **yahooweather api** using **saxparser**

```
<yweather:forecast day="Sun" date="30 Jun 2013" low="22" high="34" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Mon" date="1 Jul 2013" low="22" high="33" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Tue" date="2 Jul 2013" low="22" high="33" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="3 Jul 2013" low="23" high="36" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
```

using this code:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("yweather:forecast")){

        day1.add(attributes.getValue("day")); 
        day1.add(attributes.getValue("date"));
        day1.add(attributes.getValue("low"));
        day1.add(attributes.getValue("high"));
        day1.add(attributes.getValue("text"));
        day1.add(attributes.getValue("code"));      

        info.setweather(day1.get(0),day1.get(1),day1.get(2),day1.get(3),day1.get(4),day1.get(5));
    }
}
```

I can now get the first day. But I only want to get the second day, also not the other four days and put it in another array .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of the XML nodes is enough to figure out what the second day is:

Simply count how often you found the start of a `yweather:forecast` element.

```
private int currentDay;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("yweather:forecast")){
        if (currentDay++ != 1) return;
        // rest of your code
```

Also reset or init the counter at each document start or end.